# Print the best fit line equation in R on the chart

Tags: r

[image]

Hi , i have created the below chart using matplotlib in python.
The plot shows the best fit line for each group.

I want to replicate the same process in R and print the best fit line equation on top of each line , please suggest.

Comment: Do it? Honestly I don't see what you are asking for.

Comment: What are the equations for the lines?

Comment: You can easily do this with `ggplot2`, please provide a `dput` of your data

Comment: Further to David A's comment, have alook at http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_smooth.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague.

One build-in R function that i am aware of is `abline()`

Quoting from `?abline()` help command.

```
Description

This function adds one or more straight lines through the current plot. Usage

abline(a = NULL, b = NULL, h = NULL, v = NULL, reg = NULL,
       coef = NULL, untf = FALSE, ...)

Arguments a, b  

the intercept and slope, single values. untf    

logical asking whether to untransform. See ‘Details’. h     

the y-value(s) for horizontal line(s). v    

the x-value(s) for vertical line(s). coef   

a vector of length two giving the intercept and slope. reg  

an object with a coef method. See ‘Details’. ...    

graphical parameters such as col, lty and lwd (possibly as vectors: see ‘Details’) and xpd and the line characteristics lend, ljoin and lmitre.
```

Example image for `abline`
[image: example]

It's not really what you asked for, since it produces straight lines. But it is already the best fit line.

You could also explore `?lines` in general and see yourself what might suit you best.

Another suggestion would be to simply show an example of your code so we can see what have you done and come up with ideas concerning an implementation in R.